Modular parametrization of elliptic curves expressed as rational function of $j(\tau)$

I have learned that one can parametrize an elliptic curve using meromorphic modular functions on group $\Gamma_0(N)$ for certain level $N$. Using the example on wikipedia, the parametrization of $y^2-y=x^3-x$ is  $x(\tau) = q^{-2} + 2q^{-1} + 5+ 9q + \dots$ and $y(\tau) = q^{-3}+3q^{-2}+9q^{-1}+21+46q+\dots$ ($q = e^{2\pi i \tau}$). I have also learned how to do this for any rational elliptic curves.
Another thing I have learned is that all meromorphic modular functions on $X_0(N)$ can be expressed as rational functions of $j(\tau) = 1728 g_2(\tau)^3 / \Delta(\tau)$ and $j_N(\tau) = j(N\tau)$, where $j$ is the j-invariant (Proposition 7.5.1 in A First Course in Modular Forms by Fred Diamond and Jerry Shurman).
So my question is, am I correct to think that the modular parametrization $x(\tau)$ and $y(\tau)$ are also some rational functions of $j(\tau)$ and $j_N(\tau)$? If so, how do I find the explicit expression? I know the q-expansion for all of them, and it seems possible that some rational expression will make it work, but I don't find a way to find it. I couldn't find any material covering this, either.

Update: Although I haven't figured it out, I have got some more idea about this. If $x$ and $y$ can be written using $j$ and $j_N$, plugging the expression back to the elliptic curve equation will yield a equation about $j$ and $j_N$, which should always hold for every $q$. There is such a equation that $j$ and $j_N$ always satisfy, which is the modular polynomial. So if there is another equation that $j$ and $j_N$ also satisfy, it is likely going to have the modular polynomial as a factor. In other words, there should be a way to transform the modular polynomial into the form of elliptic curve equation to reveal parametrization using $j$ and $j_N$. However, if this idea is correct, this means the parameterization is also going to have huge coefficients, just like modular polynomials themselves. Perhaps this is what make this hard.

Second update: I managed to "verify" this for one elliptic curve, that is $y^2+y=x^3-x^2-10x-20$, or 11.a1 on LMFDB, which has the lowest conductor 11. I found the rational mapping from $(j, j_{11})$ to $(x, y)$ and recorded here. This is done by assuming $x = P(j, j_{11}) / Q(j, j_{11})$ for some polynomial $P$ and $Q$ with degree up to 11 for both $j$ and $j_{11}$, and comparing coefficients after expanding everything to their $q$-series. The coefficients are the solution of a system of 288 equations, which thankfully my computer can still handle in a reasonable time. The same goes for $y$. The result, as expected, contains very large numbers. The largest coefficient has 127 digits. I am fairly confident that this result is correct, as I verified another hundred coefficients in the q-series, which were not included in the system of equations.

You are alluding to the modularity of rational elliptic curves. I think it would be unbelievably difficult to find a general formula for a modular parametrization, given that the modularity theorem itself was conjectural until relatively recently...

Please link to the wikipedia reference  you mention in the second sentence above. Thanks!
